# (htaccess) Allow stream but disable direct link download

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am currently using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.com(/)?.*$     [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(flv|mp4|pdf|xls|doc|mov|wmv|avi|mp3)$ http://domain.com [R,NC]
```

It disabled the direct downloading, but also stops the streaming from the media player. I realize I cannot stop the downloading completely, but I would like to be able to stream from the player on one domain while hosting the files on another domain.